# MYSQL execute stored procedure in if statement or run complicated SET statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, stored-procedures, sql-update

I've got a table where the credits and debits switch when being imported occasionally - so I've got some code to set a variable and then swap if it matches, however I can't get it to run in an IF statement, I've tried to put it in a stored procedure but can't  run the stored procedure in an IF statement either. What would you recommend? see below for code. thanks

```
set @TotalCr = (select max(TotalCredit) from mbs_headers);

If (@TotalCr = (select sum(PDebit) from mbs_details) and @TotalCr =! (select sum(PCredit) from mbs_details)) 

then UPDATE mbs_detailstest SET PCredit=@tmp:=PCredit, PCredit=PDebit, PDebit=@tmp 
else 
end;
```

OR

```
set @TotalCr = (select max(TotalCredit) from mbs_headers);

If (@TotalCr = (select sum(PDebit) from mbs_details) and @TotalCr =! (select sum(PCredit) from mbs_details)) 

then exec TestSwapProc 
else 
end;
```

with TestSwapProc containing only

```
UPDATE mbs_detailstest SET PCredit=@tmp:=PCredit, PCredit=PDebit, PDebit=@tmp
```

sample data - 
table: details

```
Name, Credit, Debit
Mike, 100, 20
Mike, 10, 0
```

Table: headers

```
name, totalcredits, totaldebits
Mike, 20, 110
```

I need the Details table switched around to reflect the true value as it sometimes gets inserted in the wrong way
desired results:

Table: Details

```
Name, Credits, Debits
Mike, 20, 100
Mike, 0, 10
```

Headers table to stay the same, as it is always correct

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really  help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, Thanks for your comment, sample and desired results have been edited in, the answer below did not work for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
declare v_total decimal(10,2);
declare v_debit decimal(10,2);
declare v_credit decimal(10,2);

select max(TotalCredit) into v_total
from mbs_headers;

select sum(PDebit), sum(PCredit) into v_debit, v_credit 
from mbs_details;

If (v_total = v_debit and v_total != v_credit) then
  UPDATE mbs_detailstest 
  SET PCredit=v_debit, PDebit=v_credit; 
end if;
```